# Python Pandas eval with the formula as value

Tags: python, pandas, eval

I want to do a strange thing and I've prepared an example:

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1,2,3], 'B': [1,2,3], 'formula': ['A+B', 'A-B', 'A*B']})
```

df:

```
+---+---+---+---------+
|   | A | B | formula |
+---+---+---+---------+
| 0 | 1 | 1 | A+B     |
| 1 | 2 | 2 | A-B     |
| 2 | 3 | 3 | A*B     |
+---+---+---+---------+
```

I want to do something like that:

```py
df[C] = df.eval(df['formula])
```

to get:

```
+---+---+---+---------+---+
|   | A | B | formula | C |
+---+---+---+---------+---+
| 0 | 1 | 1 | A+B     | 2 |
| 1 | 2 | 2 | A-B     | 0 |
| 2 | 3 | 3 | A*B     | 9 |
+---+---+---+---------+---+
```

But I'm gettingan strage error:

ValueError: Wrong number of items passed 3, placement implies 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, you will get the exact output:

```
import pandas as pd
dataFrame = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1,2,3], 'B': [1,2,3], 'formula': ['A+B', 'A-B', 'A*B']})
dataFrame['C']=[x.eval(x['formula'].iloc[0]).iloc[0] for _,x in dataFrame.groupby(level=0)]
print dataFrame
```

Tested here: http://tpcg.io/xSqKh7

Answer (score 0):

Try with `groupby` and `eval`

```
df['New']=[x.eval(x['formula'].iloc[0]).iloc[0] for _,x in df.groupby(level=0)]
df
Out[270]: 
   A  B formula  New
0  1  1     A+B    2
1  2  2     A-B    0
2  3  3     A*B    9
```